# iOS UIButton with transparent title on white background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, calayer, alpha

I have a custom `UIButton` with transparent background and white title.
I'm looking for a simple solution to invert it on highlight (white background and transparent title) as it is achieved on system `UISegmentedControl`.

Is there simpler solution than inverting alpha on snapshot used as a `CALayer` mask?

If not, could you tell how can I invert `CALayer` alpha?

Comment: set the title color as button.superView.backgroundColor

Comment: But I want title to be real transparent - not superview background colour similar.

Comment: You're probably going to have to use CGMasks from what I can tell... so make the title black and the button white, then mask it to the background, then place a second button beneath the first that's just solid white.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw the text on a CGContext using Destination Out as blend mode.

This code seems to work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
    NSString* buttonText = @"BUTTON";
    CGSize buttonSize =  CGSizeMake(200, 50);
    NSDictionary* textAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};

    CGSize textSize = [buttonText sizeWithAttributes:textAttributes];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(buttonSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height)];
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeDestinationOut);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(buttonSize.width/2-textSize.width/2, buttonSize.height/2-textSize.height/2);
    [@"BUTTON" drawAtPoint:center withAttributes:textAttributes];


    UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:viewImage];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

By the way, if you want to set the UIImage in a UIButton instead of just adding it to a view:

```
UIButton* boton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, viewImage.size.width, viewImage.size.height)];
[boton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[boton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
boton.titleLabel.font = font;
[boton setTitle:buttonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[boton setImage:viewImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.view addSubview:boton];
```

Comment: I thought so... Do you think it will be simpler than taking button content snapshot and inverting alpha?

Comment: Yes, this is probably simpler. As you can see the image creation is just a few lines of code.

Comment: BTW if you found my answer useful it would be great if you accept it.

Comment: Added only `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(buttonSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);`

Comment: I've refactored snippet to the category/subclass method.

Answer (score 0):

You could set

```
-(void)viewDidload: {
    [yourButton setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color 
                     forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [yourButton addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(changeButtonBackGroundColor:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

-(void)changeButtonBackGroundColor:(UIButton *)button {
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
}
```

remember to change it back with events: `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchOutSide` :)

Comment: Thx, but if you set clearColor for title it will blend with background instead of mask it. Am I right?

Comment: yeah, it will. But why don't you save the button's backgroundColor and set it to the button when users highlight it ?

Comment: Background is not a problem. I need transparent title to see through it (only the title) all the content under the button (the keyhole effect like).