# Transparent UIButton title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, calayer

How can I subtract the shape of the title text from the button background?

[image]

I created a custom UIButton class. Currently the code to add the border and text color looks simply like this

```
layer.borderWidth = 2.0
layer.borderColor = buttonColor.CGColor
layer.cornerRadius = (CGFloat(bounds.height) + paddingVertical * 2.0) / 2.0
setTitleColor(buttonColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Any advice on how I can subtract the button title shape from background. Do I need to render all this as an image or is there a better alternative?

Comment: This can be achieved very easily if you have such image.

Comment: I am looking for a programmatic solution

Comment: little change here may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515100/ios-uibutton-with-transparent-title-on-white-background

Comment: Create a gradient layer with whatever color you want and them make it mask to your textlabel and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks, however the blurred background content is changing constantly. So unfortunatelly a *static*, non-transparent title (with or without gradient) doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written some code for you, my UIButton subclass called AKStencilButton (available on github https://github.com/purrrminator/AKStencilButton):

```
#import "AKStencilButton.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface AKStencilButton ()
{
    UIColor * _buttonColor;
}
@end

@implementation AKStencilButton

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]){
        [self setupDefaults];
    }
    return self;
}
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]){
        [self setupDefaults];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setupDefaults
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self refreshMask];
}
-(void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    [super setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:state];
}
-(void)refreshMask
{
    self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSString * text = self.titleLabel.text;
    CGSize buttonSize = self.bounds.size;
    UIFont * font = self.titleLabel.font;

    NSDictionary* attribs = @{NSFontAttributeName: self.titleLabel.font};
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:attribs];


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(buttonSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(buttonSize.width/2-textSize.width/2, buttonSize.height/2-textSize.height/2);

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height)];
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeDestinationOut);

    [text drawAtPoint:center withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
    UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
    maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id)(viewImage.CGImage);
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
@end
```

it looks like this (sorry for the rainbow):

[image]

Comment: Maybe that answers the question, but the answer should be posted _here_ on [so], not just on github.

Comment: Ok. Does it look better now?

Comment: Thanks. Looking into rewriting this in Swift now …

Answer (score 8):

**Extension for swift 4**

```
extension UIButton{
func clearColorForTitle() {

    let buttonSize = bounds.size

    if let font = titleLabel?.font{
        let attribs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]

        if let textSize = titleLabel?.text?.size(withAttributes: attribs){
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(buttonSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

            if let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(){
                ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)

                let center = CGPoint(x: buttonSize.width / 2 - textSize.width / 2, y: buttonSize.height / 2 - textSize.height / 2)
                let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize.width, height: buttonSize.height))
                ctx.addPath(path.cgPath)
                ctx.fillPath()
                ctx.setBlendMode(.destinationOut)

                titleLabel?.text?.draw(at: center, withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font])

                if let viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(){
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                    let maskLayer = CALayer()
                    maskLayer.contents = ((viewImage.cgImage) as AnyObject)
                    maskLayer.frame = bounds

                    layer.mask = maskLayer
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
button.clearColorForTitle()
```

Comment: A small remark: you need to call `clearColorForTitle()` also in `layoutSubviews()`, because when the button bounds changes to something other than the one during creation (like settings content insets programmatically) then everything will be messed up. Would also make sense to clear the title color, just in case, so that it's not visible below the "holes".

Answer (score 4):

I added the following method to UIView to solve this:

```
-(void)maskSubviews:(NSArray*)subviews {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationOut);
    for (UIView *view in subviews) {
        CGPoint origin = [view convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self];
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, origin.x, origin.y);
        [view.layer renderInContext:context];
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -origin.x, -origin.y);
    }
    UIImage* mask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.maskView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:mask];
}
```

Simply call it with the views you want masked out. For example:

```
[button maskSubviews: @[button.titleLabel, button.imageView]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I converted @purrrminator's solution to Swift 3, just the main method.

```
func clearTextButton(button: UIButton, title: NSString, color: UIColor) {
    button.backgroundColor = color
    button.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear()
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.clear(), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle(title as String, for: [])
    let buttonSize: CGSize = button.bounds.size
    let font: UIFont = button.titleLabel!.font
    let attribs: [String : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: button.titleLabel!.font]
    let textSize: CGSize = title.size(attributes: attribs)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(buttonSize, false, UIScreen.main().scale)
    let ctx: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.white().cgColor)
    let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: buttonSize.width / 2 - textSize.width / 2, y: buttonSize.height / 2 - textSize.height / 2)
    let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize.width, height: buttonSize.height))
    ctx.addPath(path.cgPath)
    ctx.fillPath()
    ctx.setBlendMode(.destinationOut)
    title.draw(at: center, withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
    let viewImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let maskLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
    maskLayer.contents = ((viewImage.cgImage) as! AnyObject)
    maskLayer.frame = button.bounds
    button.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Comment: Too many forced unwrapped optionals. Conditional unwrapping would work much better in all these cases: if let font = button.titleLabel?.font, { ... }, if let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() { ... }, etc.

Comment: @GK100 True, it was just a quick and dirty change. Some of the variables are guaranteed, like the titleLabel, as I set the title just before.